# Is there a reason why the short for `'modifiable'` is `'ma'` and not `'mo'`?

Tags: options, history-of

Is there a reason why the short for `'modifiable'` is `'ma'` and not `'mo'`?

I've entered `:h 'mo'` and I got `E149`, so there doesn't seem to be any clash...

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because there are two similarly-named options: [`'modifiable'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27modifiable%27) (shortened to `'ma'`) and [`'modified'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27modified%27) (shortened to `'mod'`).

Comment: But they don't clash... And there are many other pairs of similarly named options which have similar shorthands, e.g. `nu`/`rnu`, `wic`/`wig`, and most of all, `wcm`/`wc` where the difference is in the trailing letter of the former, just like for `mod`/could-have-been-`mo`.

Comment: This type of back-and-forth is why this site is ill-suited to 'why' questions.

Comment: @wbogacz, in general I agree. But apprently there's a `history-of` tag. I guess given that tag, going from _why_ to _do you know about the historical decision of xyz?_ is ok, no?

Comment: There seem to be a number of these questions in the past, some answered, and some accepted, so the feeling is clear they are positive. What isn't positive is the point-counterpoint that they can generate. I envision Dan Aykroyd/Jane Curtin.